# Complicate linq query which filter out duplicate value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a json as data as below :

```
  [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "shopname": "seven up",
            "shopkeeper": "John",
            "salesbooks": [
                {
                    "bookid": 11,
                    "bookname": "Tom-story",
                    "catagories" : 1,
                    "soldout": false
                },
                {
                    "bookid": 12,
                    "bookname": "Iron-Man",
                    "catagories" : 2,
                    "soldout": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "shopname": "Richmond Shop",
            "shopkeeper": "Jame",
            "salesbooks": [
                {
                    "bookid": 11,
                    "bookname": "Tom-story",
                    "catagories" : 2,
                    "soldout": false
                },
                {
                    "bookid": 13,
                    "bookname": "PeterPan",
                    "catagories" : 2,
                    "soldout": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "shopname": "Worchester Shop",
            "shopkeeper": "Jame",
            "salesbooks": [
                {
                    "bookid": 15,
                    "bookname": "Jurias Park",
                    "catagories" : 1,
                    "soldout": false
                },
                {
                    "bookid": 16,
                    "bookname": "Champion",
                    "catagories" : 1,
                    "soldout": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

My expected result should be:

```
[
            {
                "id": 1,
                "shopname": "seven up",
                "shopkeeper": "John",
                "salesbooks": [
                    {
                        "bookid": 11,
                        "bookname": "Tom-story",
                        "catagories" : 1,
                        "soldout": false
                    },
                    {
                        "bookid": 12,
                        "bookname": "Iron-Man",
                        "catagories" : 2,
                        "soldout": true
                    }
                ]
            }
]
```

Normally, if require to get shop which have book on sales , I can do it

```
var bookshop = bookshops.where(w=>w.salesbooks.any(a=>a.soldout==false));
```

But this time, if I also want to filter out if count(salesbooks.catagories) > 1?
That mean I want to filter out id:2 bookshop , as both of salesbook.catagories are same.
How to write the linq in c#?

p.s. I try

```
var bookshop = bookshops.where(w=>w.salesbooks.any(a=>a.soldout==false) && w.salebooks.GroupBy(g=>g.catagories).count==1);
```

the result is still show Richmond shop
Thank you

---

Comment: 2 options: Chain a `.Where`. before the `.Any` like so: `bookshops.Where(w => w.Salesbooks.Where(sb => sb.Catagories > 1).Any(a => a.soldout == false))` or add another condition inside your `.Any`: `bookshops.where(w => w.Salesbooks.Any(sb => sb.Catagories > 1 && sb.soldout == false));`

Comment: No, I mean if salesbooks in the shop which catagories is duplicate, in SQL term,
select * from bookshop where id in
(select shopid,catagories from salesbook where  shopid in (
SELECT shopid,  countofcatagories=count(*) FROM salesbooks GROUP BY catagories,shopid  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1))

Comment: @CarrieKaski if you could write an example of expected output for given input, that would be much better to understand your question.

Comment: You can't use `count` on `GroupBy()` result - did you mean `Count()`? C# is a language of types, show your types / classes and not JSON which is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter out bookshops with categories more than 1. In C# You can just group by categories and have a check for >1 rather than ==1 i.e.

C# code
var bookshop = bookshops.Where(w => w.salesbooks.Any(a => a.soldout == false) && w.salesbooks.GroupBy(g => g.catagories).Count() > 1;

Answer (score -1):

you can use another clause like

```
            var bookshop = bookshops.Where(w => w.salesbooks.Any(a => a.soldout == false) && !w.salesbooks.Any(a => a.catagories < 2) );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The limitation is on the value of `catagories` but rather the count of the matching values.